# Calculate running balance per product in mysql view

Tags: mysql, sql, select, view, group-by

I have a view (`vwbalance`) in mysql that i use to check the current inventory balance of our product in the store,It has been working very fine with one product.
Here is the view

```
CREATE VIEW vwbalance AS
SELECT
  a.`id`      AS `Trans No`,
  a.`tdate` AS Siku,
  a.`section` AS `Section`,
  `g`.`p_name` AS `Product`,
  a.`cr`      AS `In`,
  a.`dr`      AS `Out`,
  SUM((o.`cr` - o.`dr`)) AS `balance`,
  a.`status`  AS `status`
FROM ((`trn_inventory` a
    LEFT JOIN `mst_product` `g`
      ON ((`g`.`p_id` = a.`p_id`)))
   JOIN `trn_inventory` o
     ON (((a.`tdate` > o.`tdate`)
           OR ((a.`tdate` = o.`tdate`)
               AND (a.`id` >= o.`id`)))))
WHERE (o.`status` = 'APPROVED')
GROUP BY a.`tdate` DESC,a.`id` DESC;
```

The above view gets data from two tables `trn_inventory` where we store all inventory transactions(products coming in and products going out) and `mst_product` where we store the product details. Our main reason in creating this view is basically to show the running balance because the table trn_inventory doesnt store the balance, below is the table definition

```
CREATE TABLE trn_inventory (
  id INT(25) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  tdate DATE NOT NULL,
   p_id INT(25) NOT NULL,
   dr INT(5) DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'OUT',
  cr INT(5) DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'IN',
  cost DOUBLE(13,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  section VARCHAR(95) DEFAULT NULL,
  ref VARCHAR(95) DEFAULT NULL,
  trans_user VARCHAR(35) NOT NULL,
  `status` ENUM('PENDING','APPROVED','DISPATCHED','VOID') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'PENDING',
  approvedby VARCHAR(35) DEFAULT NULL,
  dispatchedby VARCHAR(35) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Here is the output when I run `SELECT * FROM vwbalance;`:

```
Trans  Siku      Section   Product         In   Out  Bal  Status  
-------------------------------------------------------------------
8   2014-02-05  "Store"   "Treated SEEDS"   0   10   68  "APPROVED"
7   2014-02-05  "Store"   "Treated SEEDS"  50    0   78  "APPROVED"
5   2014-02-04  "Store"   "Dry Seeds"      40    0   28  "APPROVED"
3   2014-01-16  "Store"   "Dry Seeds"       0    2  -12  "APPROVED"
4   2014-01-15  "Store"   "Dry Seeds"       0   15  -10  "APPROVED"
2   2014-01-15  "Store"   "Dry Seeds"      10    0    5      "VOID"
1   2014-01-15  "store"   "Dry Seeds"      12    0    5  "APPROVED"
6   2014-01-14  "Store"   "Dry Seeds"       0    7   -7  "APPROVED"
```

I want it to show the balance per product:

```
Trans  Siku      Section   Product         In   Out  Bal  Status  
-------------------------------------------------------------------
8   2014-02-05  "Store"   "Treated SEEDS"   0   10   40  "APPROVED"
7   2014-02-05  "Store"   "Treated SEEDS"  50    0   50  "APPROVED"
5   2014-02-04  "Store"   "Dry Seeds"      40    0   28  "APPROVED"
3   2014-01-16  "Store"   "Dry Seeds"       0    2  -12  "APPROVED"
4   2014-01-15  "Store"   "Dry Seeds"       0   15  -10  "APPROVED"
2   2014-01-15  "Store"   "Dry Seeds"      10    0    5      "VOID"
1   2014-01-15  "store"   "Dry Seeds"      12    0    5  "APPROVED"
6   2014-01-14  "Store"   "Dry Seeds"       0    7   -7  "APPROVED"
```

i have modified grouping ,

```
...
...
 WHERE (o.`status` = 'APPROVED')
    GROUP BY a.`tdate` DESC,a.`id` DESC,o.p_id;
```

but it was returning two rows for the second product below is the output

```
Trans  Siku      Section   Product         In   Out  Bal  Status  
-------------------------------------------------------------------
 8  2014-02-05  "Store"   "Treated SEEDS"   0   10   28  "APPROVED"
 8  2014-02-05  "Store"   "Treated SEEDS"   0   10   40  "APPROVED"
 7  2014-02-05  "Store"   "Treated SEEDS"  50    0   28  "APPROVED"
 7  2014-02-05  "Store"   "Treated SEEDS"  50    0   50  "APPROVED"
 5  2014-02-04  "Store"   "Dry Seeds"      40    0   28  "APPROVED"
 3  2014-01-16  "Store"   "Dry Seeds"       0    2  -12  "APPROVED"
 4  2014-01-15  "Store"   "Dry Seeds"       0   15  -10  "APPROVED"
 2  2014-01-15  "Store"   "Dry Seeds"      10    0    5      "VOID"
 1  2014-01-15  "store"   "Dry Seeds"      12    0    5  "APPROVED"
 6  2014-01-14  "Store"   "Dry Seeds"       0    7   -7  "APPROVED"
```

Where am I going wrong?

I have created an [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/16c67/1) where you can get this schema with sample data where you can test the query

Comment: You're selecting and joining by a.`tdate`, but group by a.`date` ?

Comment: i have corrected the typo

Comment: Does the result change after the correction?

Comment: the correction was a typing error but the view itself didnt have the typo.
Still no changes, any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not match product id of both tables in create view.
So, you need to set your condition as below.

```
 WHERE (o.status = 'APPROVED' and o.p_id = a.p_id)
GROUP BY a.`tdate` DESC,a.`id` DESC,o.p_id;
```

See working [FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eac502/1)